# I can't display all texts in the same embed with python from discord bot

Tags: python

ok, i'm trying to add all the texts in the same embed of a for bot for discord, but i can't do it, this is what happens to me...

[image]

It should be all in the same embed

What should I do to correct this error? Thank you very much!

this is the code i am using...

```
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="ayuda bot") 
bot.remove_command("help") p

 
@bot.command()
async def habbo(ctx):
    response = requests.get("https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-leaderboards/hhes/visited-rooms/daily/latest.json")
    data= response.json()
    


    for habbo in data:
         
         embed=discord.Embed(title=f"", description=f"{habbo['name']}", color=discord.Colour.random())
         await ctx.send(embed=embed)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("BOT listo!")   
 
    
bot.run('')
```

Someone give me a hand, thank you very much!

Comment: Each item of `data` is a dict, so your code may be that regarding the output you have, could you please show us the real code you run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send multiple embed, don't create multiple, build the content, then send one

```
@bot.command()
async def habbo(ctx):
    response = requests.get("https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-leaderboards/hhes/visited-rooms/daily/latest.json")
    data = response.json()
    content = '\n'.join(item['name'] for item in data)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"", description=f"{content}", color=discord.Colour.random())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```